# SP2016: How can I get the browser spell check to work in list item fields?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, spellchecker

In my SharePoint 2016 site, the browser's (IE, EDGE, Chrome) built in spell checker (presumably driven off of HTML5), doesn't seem to work (no red lines as you type).  It works in other sites lite twitter or stackexchange.  It also works in my custom Angular form driven from my SharePoint site.  (BTW: I'm referring to the browser's red line spell check as opposed to the "Spelling" button in the ribbon bar.)

If I inspect a list item form element (TEXTAREA) and add the spellcheck="true", then it works for the active instance of the form.  Emulation in Edge is MS Edge.

Master page is standard.  My guess is that there's an include file that set's the web page's default to not use the html5 spellcheck feature.  I've seen some other posts on stackexchange that refer to SP2010 or SP2013, but nothing for SP2016.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this and it seems to work.  Please let me know if there's a problem with this solution.

Open the form by adding a new item or editing an item.  {Gear} > Edit Form.  Add a Script Editor Web Part.  Insert the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
    window.onload = function(){document.getElementById('onetIDListForm').setAttribute("spellcheck","true")};
</script>
```

The element onetIDListForm seems to be the common name used inside the new and edit forms.  If not, this needs to be changed.